# Why does he uses a floating point in this example?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am a beginner learning Python from Learn Python the hard way. It's my first programming language that I learn and I am stuck at an exercise.

Exercise:
"Explain why the 4.0 is used instead of just 4."

```
cars = 100
space_in_a_car = 4.0 #Why does he uses 4.0 instead of 4 here?
drivers = 30
passengers = 90
cars_not_driven = cars - drivers
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
average_passengers_per_car = passengers / cars_driven


print "There are", cars, "cars available."
print "There are only", drivers, "drivers available."
print "There will be", cars_not_driven, "empty cars today."
print "We can transport", carpool_capacity, "people today."
print "We have", passengers, "to carpool today."
print "We need to put about", average_passengers_per_car, "in each car."
```

I honestly can't find any reason why he would use a floating point at line 2 other than to to serve as an example that if I have a floating point number it affects the rest of the expression evaluation(cars_driven * space_in_a_car) resulting in 120.0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: because he was too lazy to do `from __future__ import division` or to switch to python3

Comment: At line 15, wouldn't it be more accurate to say `print "We have", passengers, "passengers to carpool today."`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a simple question with a simple answer that I over-complicated for some reason.

(Assuming that you know why `3/4` returns `0` and  why `3/4.0` returns 0.75)

I took a look at the book and the code is **only** that bit, it doesn't seem to have any more to it, and it does ask:

> Explain why the 4.0 is used instead of
>   just 4.

It turns out this is a strange question since there is actually no reason for it. [David Heffernan was right all along.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360242/why-does-he-uses-a-floating-point-in-this-example/6360355#6360355)

So, when you add the `.0`, it doesn't have any effect than turning the carpool capacity in a float since you just do:

```
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
```

I can't understand what the author was aiming for, the only notable difference is again that one prints `120.0` and the other `120`

As I pointed out before:

```
average_passengers_per_car = passengers / float(cars_driven)  #added float
```

Would make (more) sense since, for example if the `passengers = 93` in the original code the average would be `3` and not `3.1` that would be in my opinion more reasonable for an average.

Sorry for the confusion, I hope I got it right now :) and that it helps!

**OLD:**

<strike>The reason probably this:</strike>

```
3/4 # returns 0
```

That is because `int/int == int`, so, 4 "fits" 0 times in 3, and no decimal point because it is an int.

You should do:

```
3/4. # returns 0.75
```

or

```
3/float(4)
```

This applies for python 2.x and not for python 3

**BUT**

This doesn't make sense at all, and unless I'm missing something I think it is "wrong"!

This would make much more sense:

```
cars = 100
space_in_a_car = 4 #not float
drivers = 30
passengers = 90
cars_not_driven = cars - drivers
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
average_passengers_per_car = passengers / float(cars_driven)  #added float
```

Since the amount of space in a car couldn't be 4 and a half seats, and the average, could be 2 and half persons, since it is a number and not actually persons.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Assuming it is a serious question, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I just can't see how any of this relates to the question as asked. Oh, and someone else is your mystery down-voter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ohh, you are right!! damn, I was assuming (many things) wrong. I will edit my answer, I completely missed the point. You were correct all along. I have also read the part of the book so I will expand my answer. Thank you. (BTW your downvote wasnt me either).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sorry about the confusion. Thank for pointing it out!

Comment: @Trufa: "So, when you remove the .0, it doesn't have any effect than turning the carpool capacity in a **float** since you just do...". I think you wanted to say: "So, when you **add**...". Anyway, I am deeply thankful for your answer.

Comment: @0101amt: Good catch! sorry about that, I've edited. Glad it helped! Good luck with the book!

Answer (score 4):

In the code as given in your question, there is no good reason for using a floating point value.

Answer (score 2):

In general, integer div is not the same than floating point div

integer div:

```
myInt = 4 / 5
myInt == 0
```

float div:

```
myFloat = 4.0 / 5.0
myFloat = 0.8
```

by making space_in_car a float, then the results of the operations are calculated as floats (no rounding)

But in this sample space_in_car is only used for multiplication .For multiplication the same goes, but the value does not change (120 is the same than 120.0). My guess is that it was intended to be used in a division to show the above mentioned properties but there was a lapsus calami.

Comment: Ok yes, but it doesn't actually make sense (in the example) since you can't have half a seat, i think it is confusing or even technically wrong. It makes much more sense to have a floating point average. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360242/why-does-he-uses-a-floating-point-in-this-example/6360379#6360379

Comment: _"lapsus calami"_ Wow ! I think so too.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in the wording: since **space_in_a_car** appears only in a multiplication, there is no possibility to observe a problem when changing its value.

A problem could be observed if the value of **drivers** was not a divisor of the value of **passengers**

See what happens when changing the value of  **drivers** :

```
form = ('space_in_a_car   : %s\n'
        'drivers          : %s\n'
        'passengers       : %s\n'
        'cars_driven      : %s\n'
        'average_passengers_per_car : %s\n\n')


for nbdrivers in (30, 30.0, 47, 47.0):

    cars = 100
    space_in_a_car = 4

    drivers, passengers = nbdrivers, 90

    cars_driven = drivers
    carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
    average_passengers_per_car = passengers / cars_driven

    print form % (space_in_a_car,
                  drivers,
                  passengers,
                  cars_driven,
                  average_passengers_per_car)
```

result

```
space_in_a_car   : 4
drivers          : 30
passengers       : 90
cars_driven      : 30
average_passengers_per_car : 3


space_in_a_car   : 4
drivers          : 30.0
passengers       : 90
cars_driven      : 30.0
average_passengers_per_car : 3.0


space_in_a_car   : 4
drivers          : 47
passengers       : 90
cars_driven      : 47
average_passengers_per_car : 1


space_in_a_car   : 4
drivers          : 47.0
passengers       : 90
cars_driven      : 47.0
average_passengers_per_car : 1.91489361702
```

Then , it is **drivers** that must be a float, not **space_in_a_car**

Answer (score 0):

```
cars =  100
space_in_a_car = 4.0
drivers = 30
passengers = 90

# 90 % 4 = 2(man), 90 / 4.0 = 22.5(car)
print "Need %d cars." % int(round(90 / 4.0))

# He wants you to think more about it.
```